# Facebook login error: Unsupported request

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to add Facebook login in my application.

Using **react-native-fbsdk-next**

Here is my code:

```
const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday']);
        if (result.isCancelled) {
            btnFacebookRef.current.setLoadingValue(false);
        } else {
            const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
...other code
```

[image: Unsupported request]

Comment: We have the exact same issue "Unsupported request", Facebook disabled our app and they provided a video showing this error. But we are not able to reproduce it.

Comment: It happen only on iOS device, with Android it working after I update `facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)`.
I have read and following this [link](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next) but it still not working

Comment: We are in the same situation.. we can reproduce it with test and production accounts but unable to solve that. No info provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem and stuck on it in 1 week. Then I found solution.

Go in your app. **Settings -> Advanced**. Make sure you have upgrade to latest sdk for both OS.

[image: Check SDK version]

For it we can follow this link to setup:

- [iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/432191854117704/?platform=ios)
- [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/432191854117704/?platform=android)

Let run and test your app in development mode with test account.

After that, let send your app (APK, IPA) to Facebook team to make your application enable in live mode.
If they need to check it on store (Google Play), just release new version with update FBSDK, make sure this version working well in development mode.
Waiting your app enable in live mode and it will be done!

Good luck for you!